# Unable to Get Description in output of the Get-ADUser command

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying the below script but I am not getting the description of AD user in output. I am getting only User IDs in the output. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong in below code? How can I get description too in the output.

```
CLS
[INT]$NumberOfUsers=0
$ListOfUsers=@()

$TotalListOfUsers = get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU= Accounts,DC=ABC,DC=XYZ,DC=local" -filter * | sort-object | Select Name,Description
foreach ($User in $TotalListOfUsers) {
if ($User -like "*Nikhil*") {
}
else {
$NumberOfUsers = $NumberOfUsers+1
$ListOfUsers = $ListOfUsers + $($User).Name + $($User).Description + "`r`n"
}
}

write-host "The total Number of users is $NumberOfUSers" 
write-host "$ListOfUsers"
#exit

if ($NumberOfUsers -gt 200) {

write-host "The total number of  user accounts is $NumberOfUsers"
}
Else {
write-host "Less than 200"
}
```

My Output of above code is like:

```
Account1 
Account2
Account3
```

I want output be like:

```
Account1   Description1
Account2   Description2
Account3   Description3
```

Comment: `get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU= Accounts,DC=ABC,DC=XYZ,DC=local" -filter *` -> `get-aduser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU= Accounts,DC=ABC,DC=XYZ,DC=local" -filter * -Properties Description`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-AdUser -Identity $user -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description
```

In your case, it should be :

```
Get-AdUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU= Accounts,DC=ABC,DC=XYZ,DC=local" -filter * -Properties Description | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Description
```

Comment: The OP only gets the Name in his output when he actually wants both Name and Description. I'm not sure how selecting only the Description would help him.

Comment: @notjustme: have you bothered to read it completely? he clearly mentioned "I am not getting the description of AD user in output". please read it carefully before answering .

Comment: He clearly says he wants both. "I want output be like"... and then some example output. Or how about "How can I get description too in the output." I guess you didn't actually read the question!

Comment: Buddy, i gave him only the description which he was facing the issue to retrieve. remaining he can get it by himself. unnecessary voting down doesnt make sense. Anyways let op question decide it

Comment: Whatever 'buddy', using your own words; "please read it carefully before answering". And as far as down vote goes, 1) you're not providing a solution and 2) I assumed you down voted me because you didn't read the original question.

Comment: is it ? i dont do unnecessary things . And i got one upvote cause its relevant.

Comment: Guys, chill and thanks for your responses. I really appreciate your valuable time in answering this question. Both of you helped in some or other way, however, what I was looking for was answered by @RanadipDutta. So thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This can be corrected easily and simplified quite a bit.

```
    $ListOfUsers = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU= Accounts,DC=ABC,DC=XYZ,DC=local" -Filter 'Name -notlike "*Nikhil*"' -Properties Description | select Name, Description | Sort-Object

    write-host "The total Number of users is $($ListOfUSers.Count)"
    write-host "$ListOfUsers"
    #exit

    # Not sure why/if you need both this and the previous count.
    if ($ListOfUsers.Count -gt 200) {

    write-host "The total number of  user accounts is $($ListOfUsers.Count)"
    }
    Else {
    write-host "Less than 200"
    }
```